# Reading properties file in shell script containing "=" character

Tags: shell, properties-file

I have two files param.properties and readParam.sh which reads parameter values from param.properties file

param.properties:

```
val1=a
val2=b=c;c=d
```

readParam.sh:

```
PROPERTY_FILE=p.properties

function getProperty {
   PROP_KEY=$1
   PROP_VALUE=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "$PROP_KEY" | cut -d'=' -f2`
   echo $PROP_VALUE
}
val1=$(getProperty "val1")
echo val1 : $val1
val2=$(getProperty "val2")
echo val2 : $val2
```

When I run script readParam.sh I get output as:

val1 : a

val2 : b

Where, val2 gives only half value(it gives only "b" instead of "b=c;c=d")

Please help me with the same

Answer (score 1):

just extend your existing codes:

change

```
cut -d'=' -f2
```

into:

```
cut -d'=' -f2-
```

However I would change your `cat|grep|cut` chain into a single awk one-liner:

```
function getProperty {
    awk -F'=' -v k="$1" '$1==k&&sub(/^[^=]*=/,"")' $PROPERTY_FILE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PROP_VALUE=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "$PROP_KEY" | cut -d'=' -f2`
```

-f2 will give you only the second parameter from the string you're cutting based on the delimiter.

since "=" is present in multiple places in a same line it will split the string in to multiple part and when you try to retrive the output using  f2 is will get you only the second part.

so use to get the rest of the values is the string after first occurrence of the delimiter.

```
PROP_VALUE=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "$PROP_KEY" | cut -d'=' -f2-`
```